# how to add working sets to eclipse common navigator?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I would love to add support for Working Sets for my Eclipse plugin that used the Common Navigator framework.

- In Eclipse bugzilla there is mention that this is supported
- None of the online manuals for the Common Navigator explain how to do it

I do not know where to start even since there is no extension point for it, and the Working Set implementation classes are all "internal". I have a very basic navigator setup showing default project resources and some additional `IFileSystem` stuff implementing `ITreeContentProvider`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the working set?

Comment: I want them to have the same effect as the java navigator, to group projects by working set in my navigator view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the working set manager using:

```
IWorkingSetManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager();
```

and from that get the visible working sets with:

```
IWorkingSet [] workingSets = manager.getWorkingSets();
```

the members of a working set can be accessed with:

```
IAdaptable [] elements = workingSet.getElements();
```

so you could use the working sets list as the input for the tree viewer and adjust your tree content provider to deal with this.

Comment: I did not try it yet, but this looks like a clear and simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, works like a charm. See my code at https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal-eclipse/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/eclipse/navigator/NavigatorContentProvider.java (and please do not blame me for all the instanceof in this code).

Answer (score 1):

In retrospect the following is a better solution. Instead of implementing `ITreeContentProvider` and traversing the working sets ourselves, we can reuse existing standard providers for the same content, which might work better.

You can use them like so:

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
   <viewerContentBinding 
        viewerId="rascal.navigator">
      <includes>
         <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent" />                      
         <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.*"/>
         <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.linkHelper"/>
         <contentExtension pattern="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.workingSets"/>
      </includes>
   </viewerContentBinding>
```

In particular the `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.workingSets` is what adds working sets capabilities to your navigator.

Adding your own content then becomes an issue of adding another content provider which ignores workingsets and projects and other kinds of resources which are already taken care of, e.g. like so:

```
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
      <navigatorContent
            activeByDefault="true"
            contentProvider="org.rascalmpl.eclipse.navigator.NavigatorContentProvider"
            id="org.rascalmpl.navigator.searchPathContent"
            labelProvider="org.rascalmpl.eclipse.navigator.NavigatorContentLabelProvider"
            name="Rascal search path"
            priority="normal">
         <triggerPoints>
          <or>
                 <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>
          </or>
         </triggerPoints>
         <possibleChildren>
            <or>
               <instanceof value="java.lang.Object"/> 
            </or>
         </possibleChildren>
         <actionProvider
               class="org.rascalmpl.eclipse.navigator.NavigatorActionProvider"
               id="org.rascalmpl.navigator.actions">
         </actionProvider>
         <commonSorter
               class="org.rascalmpl.eclipse.navigator.Sorter">
         </commonSorter>

      </navigatorContent>
      <commonWizard
            type="new"
            wizardId="rascal_eclipse.wizards.NewRascalFile">
         <enablement></enablement>
      </commonWizard>
      <commonWizard
            type="new"
            wizardId="rascal_eclipse.projectwizard">
         <enablement></enablement>
      </commonWizard>
   </extension>
```

and in the NavigatorContentProvider class we implement `getElements` and `getChildren` but only for our own additional content.